# date string that will ignore timezone offset

Tags: javascript, date

I am at (UTS-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

i.e, `new Date().getTimezoneOffset() == 300` seconds.

Now, I have a API endpoint (JSON) that returns a date string like this.

```
{
    someDate: '2016-01-01T00:40:00.000+00:00'
}
```

Here, I pass it to Date constructor like this

```js
var dateString = "2016-01-01T00:40:00.000+00:00";
var someDay = new Date(dateString);
console.log(someDay)
```

Mozilla Firefox console shows

> Date {Fri Jan 01 2016 00:40:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Summer Time)}

Google Chrome console shows

> Thu Dec 31 2015 19:40:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Chrome is taking the TimezoneOffset into consideration and Firefox is not. What can I do to get a Date that doesn't take Offset into consideration like FireFox in Chrome?

Comment: You're in for a world of pain trying to deal with this just using Javascript `Date`. Strongly recommend moment and moment-timezone if you're doing anything beyond the very basics (which it sounds like you are).

Comment: @ach: I know :( I am trying to avoid further dependencies though

Comment: I am getting same results in both browsers. What is the expected result?

Comment: @SalmanA: you need to manually change the timezone and check. As I am running a time just past midnight, to test, one should set the timezone to a negative value. I opted for a US timezone http://imgur.com/KKPCVGd

Comment: I don't have to. All I need to test is whether both browser produce similar results, which they do. My timezone is +5GMT btw.

Comment: both showed same time? I wont be sure at all. the time, didn't it change to `06:10 AM` in chrome?

Comment: regarding http://imgur.com/KKPCVGd... they _are_ same time (1451608800000). Remember, dates are stored as timestamps; `DatetoString()` _displays_ them in local timezone. Again, I ask you what is the expected output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118325/discussion-between-naveen-and-salman-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
 var dates = '2016-01-01T00:40:00.000+00:00'.split(/-|T|:/);
 var newDate = new Date(dates[0], dates[1]-1, dates[2], dates[3], dates[4]);
```

Comment: I hope it was this simple :) http://imgur.com/KKPCVGd try setting your system to another timezone and try

Comment: It's strange. Official API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) says "Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specified arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments." How do you check that dates are different in FireFox and Chrome ?

Comment: I set the time to 12:40 AM. And set the system clock timezone to -5 manually and tested. The behavior is as expected in Mozilla in my opinion.

Comment: But if you will use getters with prefix UTC (getUTCHours(), getUTCMinutes(), ...) results should be the same in Chrome and FireFox browsers

Comment: something like that worked finally I dunno why constructor didn't work. +1 thanks for your help.

Comment: @naveen : [check MDN docs _Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) __is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This hack works (not very clean, but does the job)

```
var dateString = '2016-07-27T01:40:30';
var dateParts = dateString.split(/-|T|:/);
var saneDate = new Date(
    +dateParts[0], 
    dateParts[1] - 1, 
    +dateParts[2], 
    +dateParts[3], 
    +dateParts[4], 
    +dateParts[5]);
console.log(saneDate);
```